# ParseMultipartForm() returning nil when ErrNotMultipart

Tags: http, go

http://golang.org/src/pkg/net/http/request.go

Why it returns to nil when ErrNotMultipart?

```
mr, err := r.multipartReader()
767     if err == ErrNotMultipart {
768         return nil 
769     } else if err != nil {
770         return err
771     }
```

In my case, I had a typo from my header

```
multipart/form-data, boundary=xxxx
```

The above should have a semi-colon instead of a comma. Now, I was tracing this for hours, because I thought ParseMultipartForm processed the data successfully.

There could be a strong reason why it was forced to nil, judging from the code.

(I posted this same question at golang-nuts group, but when I posted a reply to the first collaborator, my reply was not posted successfully. So, I think stackoverflow is a better tool for posting this question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you did it right in the first place to write to golang-nuts instead of here.

This does indeed look like a bug and should therefore be discussed in the [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/go/issues/list) or
on [golang nuts](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/golang-nuts). Note that golang-nuts is moderated and therefore your posts will not appear 
immediately (which might have happened to you).

As a workaround you can use `Request.MultipartReader` and do the reading by yourself
(copied from `ParseMultipartForm`):

```
mr, err := r.multipartReader() // don't forget to handle err
f, err := mr.ReadForm(maxMemory) // don't forget to handle err

for k, v := range f.Value {
    r.Form[k] = append(r.Form[k], v...)
}
r.MultipartForm = f
```

Judging from what I can deduce from the code history, this was simply overlooked. The
changes are from [2011](http://code.google.com/p/go/source/detail?r=4449389b968ec82b0e9b7382d27ebb333c22f4d0) and the review for the particular lines of code can be found
[here](https://codereview.appspot.com/4431068/diff/6001/src/pkg/http/request.go#newcode648). The tests don't seem to cover this particular parse error. The review
even says:

> > On 2011/04/28 00:08:40, bradfitz wrote:
> >     I think you'll always return an error here for multipart forms.  See comment
> >     above.
>
> Fixed.

Which was done for almost all errors but this one. So, as I said, I think it is a bug.